# One-line destructuring and reassignment in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, variable-assignment, babeljs

Is there a more concise way of rewriting this code:

```
const { foo, bar } = oldObj;
const newObj = { foo, bar };
```

as one-line?

Comment: What's the point of this?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Brevity.

Comment: This has already been asked a couple of times. Please search. The basic answer is no, there's no easier way.

Answer (score -4):

```
const newObj = Object.assign({}, oldObj);
```

Comment: This will copy all properties of `oldObj`

Comment: Good point, although the question was ambiguous in this regard.